# qt: using one QWS for all processes

Tags: c++, qt, embedded

I'm working on embedded system and I successively run applications.

The following process does not start until the previous has finished its work.

Every process uses `Qt` windowing server. `QWS` startup takes time and therefore we would like to do it once for all application.

How can I do it better?

Comment: Why don't you use a multitasking single process? Is Qt5 applicable on your platform?

Comment: What do you mean talking about multitasking single process? Unfortunately I use qt 4.7(but anyway  please tell more about multitasking single process)

Comment: I meant, use a single "program" that launches your task sequentially instead of start different task as multiple process. In that way you can load/launch QWS once.

Comment: Yes now I understand about single program.... It is other question, I cannot consider your suggestion as solution. I need run separate processes.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot launch QWS as a "global service". Each process must be lounched with -QWS option.

Comment: Other idea I'm trying  - make simple daemon with code:

Comment: Other idea I'm trying  - make simple daemon with code:

    #include
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      // Start the qtapp thread in server mode
      QApplication app(argc, argv, QApplication::GuiServer);
      return app.exec();
    }
Than run it at first  - after that all other processes will use it as qws server. But something went wrong I have crash ofter running first process